# Program displays random lists data when reading from file

Tags: c, list, binaryfiles

I have a homework task to create a linked list with data about excursions and write the data in a binary file and then read it.But when I write a function to display all lists, it displays the lists I have created but also shows random data.

I have tried using different loops but for some reason with for loop it doesn't display anything, just crashes. I am a beginner in C so I am sorry if the question is too stupid... :D

```
typedef struct {
    char ID[20];
    char date[11];
    int duration;
    double price;
} excursion;

typedef struct Trip {
    excursion data;
    struct Trip *next;
} trip;


trip *head=NULL;
trip *current=NULL;


void displayALL()
{
        trip *temp;

        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
                printf("ID of Excursion is %s\nDuration is %d days\nDate of departure is %s\nThe price is %.2f\n",
                                temp->data.ID, temp->data.duration, temp->data.date, temp->data.price);
                temp = temp->next;
        }
}
```

I won't be showing the entire code because the other part works
I write the lists with this code:

```
FILE * fp;
trip *temp;

if ((fp = fopen("Excursion.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
}

for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        if (fwrite(&temp->data, sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1) {
                printf("Error in writing file\n");
                exit(0);
        }
}
fclose(fp);
```

and read with this one :

```
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen("Excursion.bin", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("No info added yet\n");
        exit(1);
}
while (1) {
        trip *temp = (trip*)malloc(sizeof(trip));
        if (head == NULL) {
                head = temp;
                current = head;
                current->next = NULL;
        } else {
                current->next = temp;
                current=temp;
                current->next = NULL;
        }
        if (fread(&temp->data, sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1) {
                break;
                printf("Error reading file\n");
                exit(0);
        }
}
fclose(fp);
```

This is the random data it displays:
ID of Excursion is └
Duration is 0 days
Date of departure is
The price is 0.00
ID of Excursion is И#▌
Duration is -202182160 days
Date of departure is фхцчшщъыьэюяЁёЄєЇїЎў°∙·√№¤■ а5▐
The price is -1.#R

Comment: `if(fwrite(&temp->data,sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)` temp->data is already a pointer to a character array, so remove the `&` from there. Also `if(fread(&temp->data, sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)` Again remove the `&`. Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Could you indent your code properly?

Comment: Your code had missing semicolons (`;`), mismatch in the number of opening and closing braces (`{}`), and many more problems. Please, before asking a question, check that at least your code compiles, and fix all those obvious problems before asking the question.  This code can NOT print weird characters as you're saying it does, because it can NOT compile.

Comment: I am sorry if I have missed something this is the first time i ask a question here, I didn't want to write the whole code because I thought that it will be inconvenient. I may have missed something when re-writing here

Comment: if I remove & at temp->data it says that there is incompatible type for argument 1 of fwrite and if I leave it only temp it displays just one random list: Excursion with expired date is └
The date of the excursion is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issues are right here.

```
if(fread(&temp->data, sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)
```

And here

```
if(fwrite(&temp->data,sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)
```

So it appears you're trying to write an entire structure to your file and read the entire structure but for some reason you're telling it to put it in data, or take it out of data. Data is not is the whole structure it's 11 byte character array inside the structure.

Do this.

```
if(fread(temp, sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)
```

And

```
 if(fwrite(temp,sizeof(excursion), 1, fp) != 1)
```